# ExpressJS Response data undefined?

Tags: angularjs, express

How can a message be sent from Express to Angular?  I can log the response, and see the variable I want, however Angular complains that the variable is undefined.

On the server, I'm doing...

```
return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Life is good!' });
```

In angular, I'm doing...

```
angular.module('app').
    controller('testCtrl', function($scope, TestSvc, notify, $state){
        $scope.doSomething = function(){
            TestSvc.doSomething($scope.testValue).then(
                function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    //notify(response.data.message);
                    //notify(response.message);
                    //notify('Success');
                    $state.go('confirm');
                },
                function(response){
                    notify.notify(response.data.message);
                });
        }
    });
```

The service looks correct:

```
angular.module('app').
    factory('TestSvc', function($q, $http){

        var _doSomething = function(value){
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/api/test-service', { testValue: value }).
                then(function(){
                    d.resolve();
                }, function(response){
                    d.reject(response.data.reason);
                });
            return d.promise;
        };

        return {
            doSomething: _doSomething
        };
    });
```

And the client's log shows the following for the Response:

```
{ "message":"Life is good!" }
```

I've tried using `response.data.message`, `response.message`, `response.body.message` ... all come back as `undefined`.  What the heck am I doing wrong?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your 'then' block whitin the service change to this (changes the resolve):

```
$http.post('/api/test-service', { testValue: value }).
            then(function(data){
                d.resolve(data);
            }, function(response){
                d.reject(response.data.reason);
            });
        return d.promise;
```

Comment: Very interesting.  Why can I see it in the log function AFTER the resolve if I cannot access it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'client log'?

Comment: In Angular's controller I'm calling console.log and passing in the Response... or, at least, the result of the Resolve from the Service.  The log function .... WAIT ... I've been looking at the RESPONSE HEADERS... not the log.  Ooof.  =/